# property of type list<t> modifying the original set of values in the list<t> even when it's readonly

Tags: c#

```
class Numbers
{
    List<int> num;
    public Numbers()
    {
        num = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
    public List<int> GetNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            return num;
        }

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Numbers n = new Numbers();
        List<int> l = n.GetNumbers;
        n.GetNumbers[0] = 10; //Modification done in the original set.
        foreach (int x in l)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

}

how-come the value of original list of numbers{1,2,3,4) is getting modified through GetNumbers property even when the GetNumbers property is readonly.

Comment: What makes you think it is readonly? List<> is a reference type

Comment: A read-only property simply blocks you from assigning to *it*, not the underlying data structure it references (e.g. `n.GetNumbers[0] = 10;` is just fine, but you cannot do `n.GetNumbers = new List<int>();`).

Answer (score 4):

The `readonly` keyword means the variable is read-only -- but it doesn't guarantee that the object itself is immutable.  For illustration:

```
class Numbers
{
    readonly List<int> num;
    public Numbers()
    {
        // ok - can write to read-only variables in the owner's constructor
        num = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }

    void Test()
    {
        // this is fine -- I'm not writing to "num", just changing its state
        num.Clear();

        // compiler error: "a readonly field cannot be assigned to"
        num = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

If you want a read-only collection, there are .Net types that serve that purpose; see for example [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).

---

Related: [Eric Lippert's famous article on different kinds of immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx).